# Tables for layout? Why not?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Why not use tables for layout? I don't see what's the big deal. All my sites use a CMS so presentation is separated from the content from the get go.

And some things are easier to do with tables... like columns of equal height. Sure there are plenty of hacks and tricks but why do it? Where did this idea that it's wrong to use tables for layout come from anyway? From someone who had hundreds of actual .html documents on his site? Pfffft.

Seriously, if there are better reasons not to use tables (actual sane reasons, not connected to hungry kids in Africa or blind Internet users), I'd like to know. Because I really want to make three columns of equal height and I don't want it to take longer than 20 seconds.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: What's you name? I'll make sure to never hire you.

Comment: Also catering to blind internet users is a pretty sane reason

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you are doing a layout done in divs is much quicker to produce.  Additionally it requires less code, is cleaner, more readable, and more flexible should the design change.  Tables are for tabular data not for layout.

I don't mean to be mean but it isn't 2003 anymore you really should have learned the basics of table-less layout by now.

Answer (score 1):

- [Why Tables Are Bad (For Layout)](http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html)
- [Why tables for layout is stupid](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)